# Como faço para usar o intervalo de datas no Progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl

estou fazendo um programa para listar

- listar cliente
- Quantidade de pedidos
- Quantidade de pedidos por cliente

tudo referente ao mes de fevereiro de 2015

como eu faria pra pegar somente o intervalo de

```
>= 01/02/2015 && <=  28/02/2015
```

Comment: qual o nome do seu campo data?

Comment: consegui meu chefe me ajudou

Comment: ficou assim 

FOR EACH ped-venda WHERE MONTH(ped-venda.dt-emissao)= 2 
                     AND YEAR(ped-venda.dt-emissao) = 2015 BREAK BY ped-venda.nome-abrev BY ped-venda.dt-emissao DESC:

Comment: Coloca tua resposta e finaliza o post para que possa ajudar mais pessoas.

Answer (score -1):

Vi que voce fez ali no comentario.
Mas usar funcoes que necessitem do valor da tabela que voce esta pesquisando automaticamente transforma o for each em um full table scan, ou seja, ele nao vai conseguir aplicar indices na sua query. Em bancos com numero grande de pedidos, essa pratica joga a sua performance no lixo.
Eu faria desse jeito:

```
FOR EACH ped-venda WHERE ped-venda.dt-emissao >= 02/01/2015 
     AND ped-venda.dt-emissao <= 02/28/2015 
 BREAK BY ped-venda.nome-abrev BY ped-venda.dt-emissao DESC:
```

Sendo a data fixa, como voce sugeriu. Isso faz com que o Progress utilize o indice mais apropriado, acelerando bastante a busca do result set da sua query.